# docker-compose down not persisting postgresql data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: application
    build: .cloud/php
    image: app-application
    depends_on:
      - pgres
    ports:
      - "9050:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    networks:
      - application_network

  nginx:
    container_name: application.nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8050:8000"
    volumes:
      - .cloud/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:cached
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - application_network

  pgres:
    container_name: application.postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "54325:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: application
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      PGDATA: /tmp
    volumes:
      - .cloud/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - application_network
networks:
  application_network:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose down, postgresql data is not persisting and database resets completely. I tried to put the postgresql volume into its own /postgresql/data folder but still same result. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think it has to do something with the way you're using `PGDATA`. If you don't understand it, I would remove it. On [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) they're suggesting to define it as a subdirectory of `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I also looked at the [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/12/docker-entrypoint.sh) but didn't quite understand how they're using that env variable.

Comment: Perhaps, the other thing you could try is `.cloud/postgres/data:/tmp` instead of `.cloud/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, removing PGDATA did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```yaml
    environment:
      PGDATA: /tmp
    volumes:
      - .cloud/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

With the `PGDATA` env var, you are setting the [cluster data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/storage-file-layout.html) explicitly. So, what it does is, once you start your container (e.g. via `docker-compose up`), Postgres server will persist your db data as per your `PGDATA` setting within the `/tmp` directory.
On the other hand you are mounting a different path in the container (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) instead of the `/tmp` path. Thus once you run `docker-compose down`, the container and the persisted data in `/tmp` will be gone for good, since `/tmp` is not set as mounting point. So, unless you really need to do so, you better not touch it at all.

A working configuration might look so (shortened for the sake of brevity):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  pgres:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version or a specific version e.g. postgres:10.12
    volumes:
      - .cloud/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
```

Another thing is, even let's say you configured it via `PGDATA` like so

```yaml
    environment:
      PGDATA: /tmp
    volumes:
      - .cloud/postgres/data:/tmp
```

It wouldn't be a good idea, since the path `/tmp` is in your case, as the name `tmp` (**temporary**) suggests, really not reliable. `docker-compose down` will probably not affect it at all, but on the next boot, i.e. once you run `docker-compose up` again, the underlying OS (Linux) will very much likely delete the content of the directory `/tmp`, therefore the mounted local dir `.cloud/postgres/data` will be also immediately emptied and your persisted data will be gone. In any case the `/tmp` dir is somewhat managed by Linux, thus the data saved there might simply disappear any time - so don't rely on it!

Comment: Teşekkürler, PGDATA env kaldırınca çalıştı :) For the future readers, removing PGDATA from env solves the problem.